# What website provides man pages where the command options are linkable?

Tags: linux, web-apps

#### Context

Often when writing something related to Linux commands I want to mention the use of an option of a command.

For example, I could write something like:

> You could use the `tail -f <file>` command to get a scrolling log, here's more information on the `-f` option.

I can link to [various](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) [websites](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) that [show](https://ss64.com/bash/tail.html) the full `man` page of `tail`, but I cannot find a website where I can link to the description of the `-f` option directly.
The recipient of the message always needs to scroll or do a search for the option I refer to.

#### Question

Is there a `man` page website that provides anchors or tags for the command options such that I can link to it directly? Ideally I would be able to link to something like `somesite.org/man/commandname#option-name`.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried searching or asking on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Also try the unix tool "man2html" to see if it generates what you want using your own system's help file. Then you can use that if it works...

Comment: @ZZ, thanks for the suggestion on man2html, however then I would need to host my own webpage to which I can refer other people. It's possible, but I was hoping an existing solution would exist. If no answers will be created I will delete this question and will post it on the unix site (as cross-posting is discouraged).

Comment: Does [this](https://man.openbsd.org/tail.1#f) count?

Comment: @ssbssa Definitely! Can you add that as an answer? Also, if you know of a similar site for GNU man pages, feel free to add that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, you are looking for explainshell.com

https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=tail+-f+file

[image]

Other example for `ls -ltrapR`

https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-ltrapR

Answer (score 1):

How about generating with `man2html`, filtering as required, and hosting on a gh-pages (or gitlab pages) repository?

[tail -f](https://jsmaniac.github.io/man-pages/man1/tail.1#2)

This was generated with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

touch .nojekyll

: > index.html

for m in /usr/share/man/**/*(.); do
    target="${m#/usr/share/man/}";
    target="${target%.gz}";
    printf %s\\n "$target";
    printf %s\\n "$target" | sed -e 's/&/&amp;/g' | sed -e "s/'/\&quot;/g" | sed -e 's/</\&lt;/g' | sed -e 's/>/\&gt;/g' | sed -e 's~.*~<a href="&">&</a><br />~' >> index.html
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$target")";
    man2html "$m" | sed -ne '/^$/,$p' | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$k=0};s/<DT>/"<DT id=\"" . ++$k . "\">"/e' > "$target.html";
done
```

I can't promise I'll keep these online (most pages seem to have a COPYRIGHT section which specifies the open-source license that they use, and I don't think I have any proprietary packages installed, but I might've missed a couple in which case I'll take them down if I notice or anyone else points it out) or that I won't improve the links, so if you actually want reliable permalinks, host your own copy by forking [the repo](https://github.com/jsmaniac/man-pages/) :).